# Intel Gen8 architecture calculating total kernel instances per execution unit

Tags: opencl, intel, gpgpu, simd

I am taking the reference from the [intel_gen8_arch](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/71/a2/Compute%20Architecture%20of%20Intel%20Processor%20Graphics%20Gen8.pdf)

Few sections are causing confusion in my understanding for SIMD engine concept.

**5.3.2 SIMD FPUs**
Within each EU, the primary computation units are a pair of SIMD floating-point units (FPUs).
Although called FPUs, they support both floating-point and integer computation. These units
can SIMD execute up to four 32-bit floating-point (or integer) operations, or SIMD execute up to
eight 16-bit integer or 16-bit floating-point operations. Each SIMD FPU can complete simultaneous add and multiply
(MAD) floating-point instructions every cycle. Thus each EU is capable of 16 32-bit floating-point
operations per cycle: (add + mul) x 2 FPUs x SIMD-4.

The above lines of the documents clearly states the maximum floating point operations that can be done on each Execution Unit.

First doubt:
I think it is referring to per hardware thread of Execution unit than the whole execution unit.

**In section 5.3.5** it mentions
On Gen8 compute architecture, most SPMD programming models employ this style code
generation and EU processor execution. Effectively, each SPMD kernel instance appears to
execute serially and independently within its own SIMD lane. In actuality, each thread executes
a SIMD-Width number of kernel instances concurrently. Thus for a SIMD-16 compile of a
compute kernel, it is possible for SIMD-16 x 7 threads = 112 kernel instances to be executing
concurrently on a single EU. Similarly, for a SIMD-32 compile of a compute kernel, 32 x 7
threads = 224 kernel instances could be executing concurrently on a single EU.

Now this section illustration seems contradicting with the section 5.3.2.

Specifically,
1) Since it says each HW thread of EU has 2, SIMD-4 units then how SIMD-16 works. How are we reaching to calculation of 224 on 7 threads.

Also, How we compile the kernel in SIMD-16 or SIMD-32 mode?

Comment: The SIMD-16 is only "logical" so to speak, each SIMD-4 FPU executes 4 instructions in a sequential fashion. You don't compile for SIMD-16 or SIMD-32, you simply write your code to use the appropriate vector types (respectively 32 and 16 bits).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 5.3.2. section is indeed saying that each *EU* can perform 16 32-bit ops.
Each EU has two FPU's each of which can do 4 ops.

```
2 pipes * 4 ops per pipe * 2   (since mad's are add+mul) = 16 ops per cycle
```

There are 7 threads per EU (see figure 3), but the EU can only choose instructions from two of the 7 (that are ready) (one instruction for each pipe).

As Mai alluded above, think of a SIMD16 instructions as 4 of those SIMD4 ops.  Hence, it takes 4 cycles to complete one.  A SIMD32 instruction will take 8 cycles through those same SIMD4 pipes.  So regardless of the SIMD width the machine throughput is the same (theoretically).  "Wider" SIMD just means you use more registers and fewer threads per workload.

There's no easy way to choose the kernel compilation width (SIMD8, SIMD16, or SIMD32) and you probably don't want to do that for most workloads.  Nevertheless, there is an Intel extension your driver might support [cl_intel_subgroups](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/extensions/intel/cl_intel_subgroups.txt) that lets you control the thread width.  (You have to annotate the kernel with a special attribute.)  This can be useful if you want to SIMD channels (lanes) to share data with each other directly (without extra loads to SLM or global memory).

Also check out [this presentation](https://intel.activeevents.com/sf14/connect/sessionDetail.ww?SESSION_ID=1312) from IDF.  Slides 80-87 illustrate the mapping from compiler SIMD (e.g. SIMD32 or SIMD16) to the EU's.

Comment: Can you add explanation how SIMD-32 will work into your answer?

Comment: Sure. Edited the answer to contain this.